# Error Passing array into Database

Tags: php, arrays, database, string

```
<?php 
include "connect.php";
$device_id=rand(10000,100000);
$data_track= $_POST['tracker'];
    $data_contact= $_POST['contact_track'];
    print_r($data_track);
    print_r(count($data_contact));
    $abs=count($data_contact);
    for($x = 0; $x <$abs; $x++) {
        $insert_query = "INSERT INTO hwt_devices(device_ID,device_wemail,device_wcontact) VALUES('$device_id','$data_track[$x]','$data_contact[$x]')";
        $result_insert = mysql_query($insert_query);
        echo "hello";
    }
?>
```

I have passed array from one file to another and I want to store this array as a single String value in Database. The above code is entering only one value but I have pass three values in array.
**help me with this, I am new in PHP**

Comment: Can you show your form, or what sort of data you're getting in $_POST, and what you expect it to insert in to the database?

Comment: I found the error!!!!!!!! thank you

Answer (score 0):

First of all you can't pass the complete array from one page to another you have to use **serialize** of PHP at that page then you **unserialize** it at your getting page.
Then change this to a comma separated string using **implode** .

Comment: I have printed array in 2nd page and it is printing whole array.Another thing I dont want to store whole array in a single field that's why I am not using serialize

Answer (score 0):

`serialize()` converts your array into string. You can `serialize` your array than save it in database.

When retrieving from database you can use `unserialize()` to convert it back to array.

Comment: I know! But no matching with my requirement, for every element in array, a new entry must be create in database

Comment: Output of Print_r($data_track) :Array ( [0] => sadad [1] => sdasda [2] => sadasda )

Comment: try `mysql_query($insert_query) or die (mysql_error());` This will print if there is any error in your query.